# Downloading csv file from code

Tags: c#, download

At google insight we can search a keyword and download the result by clicking the "Download .csv" file button.
I coded the process to run on multiple keywords.

When I download the `.csv` file from google insight and open it in notepad I get this format.

```
Web Search Interest: hockey
Alabama (United States); Alaska (United States); Arizona (United States); Arkansas (United States); California (United States)
2004 - present

Interest over time
Week,Alabama,Alaska,Arizona,Arkansas,California
2004-01-04 - 2004-01-10,0,41,9,0,5
2004-01-11 - 2004-01-17,10,29,9,0,5
2004-01-18 - 2004-01-24,5,37,8,0,5
2004-01-25 - 2004-01-31,7,20,8,0,5
2004-02-01 - 2004-02-07,6,31,9,0,5
2004-02-08 - 2004-02-14,8,31,8,0,6
2004-02-15 - 2004-02-21,4,36,9,0,5
2004-02-22 - 2004-02-28,4,27,7,0,5
2004-02-29 - 2004-03-06,10,26,7,0,6
2004-03-07 - 2004-03-13,14,34,15,0,7
2004-03-14 - 2004-03-20,4,58,8,0,5
2004-03-21 - 2004-03-27,5,28,10,0,5
2004-03-28 - 2004-04-03,6,18,8,0,5
2004-04-04 - 2004-04-10,4,31,6,0,5
2004-04-11 - 2004-04-17,4,16,7,0,4
2004-04-18 - 2004-04-24,4,18,6,0,5
2004-04-25 - 2004-05-01,6,20,6,0,4
200
```

However when I download it from code using:

```
byte[] csv = client.DownloadData(url);
File.WriteAllBytes(path, csv);
```

I get this format:

```
Web Search Interest: football
Alabama (United States); Wisconsin (United States); Wyoming (United States)
2004 - present

Interest over time
Week    Alabama Wisconsin   Wyoming
2004-01-04 - 2004-01-10 14  10  0
2004-01-11 - 2004-01-17 10  7   7
2004-01-18 - 2004-01-24 10  7   7
2004-01-25 - 2004-01-31 10  7   7
2004-02-01 - 2004-02-07 13  8   7
2004-02-08 - 2004-02-14 9   6   0
2004-02-15 - 2004-02-21 7   5   0
2004-02-22 - 2004-02-28 8   5   0
2004-02-29 - 2004-03-06 5   4   0
2004-03-07 - 2004-03-13 5   5   0
2004-03-14 - 2004-03-20 7   4   6
2004-03-21 - 2004-03-27 8   4   7
2004-03-28 - 2004-04-03 7   5   7
2004-04-04 - 2004-04-10 5   3   8
2004-04-11 - 2004-04-17 7   4   8
2004-04-18 - 2004-04-24 7   5   8
2004-04-25 - 2004-05-01 7   6   6
```

But my requirement is to get the code in the first format as it is to be uploaded somewhere where the first format is needed. What is wrong with my code and why is the format changing?

I am using this url behind the button:

```
<a title="" onclick="trends.PageTracker.trackSoph('exprt');" class="" href="http://www.google.com/insights/search/overviewReport?q=hockey&amp;geo=US-AL%2CUS-AK%2CUS-AZ%2CUS-AR%2CUS-CA&amp;cmpt=geo&amp;content=1&amp;export=1" id="exportLink"><div style="vertical-align: middle; float: left" class="goog-inline-block fs04img SPRITE_csv"></div><span style="text-decoration: underline; color: white; float: left;">&nbsp;</span>Download as CSV</a>
```

Code that assign the value to url:

```
 HtmlElement getDownloadLink = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("exportLink");
            if (getDownloadLink != null)
            {
                string link = string.Empty;
                link = getDownloadLink.GetAttribute("href");
                downloadsheet(link, dir + textBox1.Text + filecounter + ".csv");
                filecounter = filecounter + 1;


            }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are downloading the exact same path? It looks like the download link version may be passing arguments to tell it to be comma separated instead of tab separated.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Kindly see the question i have update at the end ,Thankyou

Comment: Please also include the code that assigns a value to `url`

Comment: Just a thought i am not replacing amp; in the link ,,,maybe this is the issue?

Comment: If you put a brekpoint in, what value does `link` have?

Comment: About the amp issue, that very likely could cause it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain just checked by replacing the amp; still same thing.The link i get is
 /insights/search/overviewReport?q=football&geo=US-AL%2CUS-MO%2CUS-MT%2CUS-NE%2CUS-NV&cmpt=geo&content=1&export=2

Then i attach the front part (http://www.google.com) and use webclient to download it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `export=2` in your code at the breakpoint but it is `export=1` in the website code.

Comment: :) i just spotted it too and it worked with export = 1 ...
Thanks a lot ,still curious how the link changes from 1 to 2 :o...

Comment: Likely it was set from a option checkbox/radial elsewhere on the page/previous page that you set when you navigated by hand but did not set through code